# Can I set up Thunderbird such that emails are automatically grouped by the senders I prescribe?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Can I set up my **Thunderbird** such that emails are grouped by the **senders I prescribe?** I want them to be placed in certain folders when they come in, rather than moving them manually after that. For example, emails from a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com will automatically go to a folder I would like to open every morning, and then d@outlook.com and e@outlook.com to another folder that I will check casually (e.g on taxi, subway). Not a fan of the Important/Others classifier of Outlook; I'm just tired of browsing a pile of Important emails every time. Also, for two or three groups of emails I would like to be sure.

Comment: You mean the filter function?

Comment: ProTip: In the viewing pane, you can click on the address and choose to create a filter based on that address. You can also do that with things like the subject. It's not evident, or intuitive, but the function is there. I can grab you a screenshot if this doesn't make it clear, but click around and you'll find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what the "Message Filters" function is designed to do. "Tools" - "Message Filters" allows you to set up filters that automatically can act on incoming messages, but that you also can run on messages that are already stored. It would be a matter of creating the desired folder structure, then have filters automatically move messages to one of these folders based on the sender.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in Thunderbird.

Select the Inbox of the folder you wish to sort then at the top of the view menu click on `Correspondents`

[image]

[reference](https://emailmate.com/blog/2019/05/group-email-conversations-sender/)